# Laravel local scope [BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method]

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel scope, I followed as instructed in laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes) for local scope but it through the error of `BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Models\User::active()`  my scope code is here

User.php
namespace App\Models\User;

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
     $query->where('id',1);
}
```

and using scope code is here

// web.php  route file

```
$user = User::active()->get();
```

Comment: Please provide file name of both function.

Comment: question updated

Comment: does this `User` class extend from `Model`?

Comment: Please provide full code of. model and route file

Answer (score -2):

You are missing the `return`

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
     return $query->where('id',1);
}
```

Comment: it is as Laravel docs example but I tried it before with return keyword always give the same error for all models

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @migsAV return is not required strictly

Comment: @MANSOORKOCHY apologies I see the error. I cannot replicate the error, try maybe clearing your cache with php artisan optimize:clear and see if that helps

Comment: @Mike ok cool thanks, didn't know that

Comment: Thanks from all of you, the problem was with ide-helper where it was missing scope method from Builder model, I followed the step back and it was changed to 'scopes' instead of 'scope' for some reason that I don't know if some in find the perks of this issue please describe it more in-depth

Comment: As of Laravel 10, a local scope is a void function which doesn't return a value.